# Is "malo" in "lo malo" noun or adjective?

Tags: sustantivos, adjetivos, categorías-gramaticales

In phrases such as "olvidar lo malo y lo feo" and "lo mismo" what are "malo", "feo" and "mismo"? Are they nouns or adjectives?

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4913/de-qu%c3%a9-manera-funciona-el-lo-neutral/4916#4916

Comment: Both, in a way.  Adjectives that are being used as abstract nouns, syntactically, they are nouns in the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Son nombres creados a partir de un adjetivo, "adjetivos substantivados".

Comment: Esta respuesta ganaría un poco más si la ampliases un poco, por ejemplo con la definición de adjetivo sustantivado y otros ejemplos. Te recomiendo, si no lo has hecho ya, visitar las secciones de [tour], [help] y [answer]. Por cierto, tal y como está ahora esta respuesta aparece en las colas de revisión como "low quality", quizá por su brevedad.